# Why am I not getting DeadlineExceededError with this GCP App Engine app?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I'm trying to better understand Google App Engine, specifically the request processing time limits. On the documentation it states:

> A request handler has a limited amount of time to generate and return
>   a response to a request, typically around 60 seconds. Once the
>   deadline has been reached, the request handler is interrupted.

I understood that to mean that a call to the sleep function below (via the [project-id].appspot.com/sleep url) would result in an error, but that is not the case. I've ran it for 600 seconds and it still returned the expected response.

```
import time
from flask import Flask

# If `entrypoint` is not defined in app.yaml, App Engine will look for an app
# called `app` in `main.py`.
app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route("/")
def hello():
    """Return a friendly HTTP greeting."""
    return "Hello World!"


@app.route("/sleep")
def sleep():
    sleep_time = request.args.get("time", default=120, type=int)
    time.sleep(sleep_time)
    return f"slept {sleep_time} seconds"
```

Comment: Standard python 3.7 (2nd gen) environment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two things are happening: App Engine is being generous here, and you haven't quite exceeded the limit. I tried the following app:

```
import time
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello():
    """Return a friendly HTTP greeting."""
    time.sleep(1000000)

    return "Hello World!"
```

And it timed out after **601.9 seconds**. I'm sure you'll get similar behavior if you try longer times, but generally you shouldn't depend on the extra runtime being available.